# jquery sort table rows based on the custom column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I do have the below html having table data.

```
<table id="decisionTable" class= "CSSTableGenerator" width ="100%" border =1 id="table1">
  <tr color="23145">
       <th><b>CheckList</b></th>
       <th><b>Health</b></th>
       <th><b>Comments</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of Failed Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Green</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of mobile Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Select</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of Success Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Red</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of unknown Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Amber</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of mixed Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Select</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've to sort table rows based on the values present in `Health`. I want the table rows having `Select` value in `Health` column to be shown on top of the    table.

I've managed to write below jquery to find the `td` value present in `Health` column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#decisionTable tr').each(
            function() {
                console.log($(this).find('td[id="health"]')
                        .text());
            });
});
```

I got to know there is an in-built jquery function `Jquery.sort()` to get this done, however I'm not sure how to sort based on the `Select` value alone in the `Health` column.

Any help would be much appreciable.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all don't use overlapping ids, if you need duplicate identifiers, use classes or data instead, as you've already used. Also, what do you mean by `sort`, sort it alphabetically? Hide the non-health stuff?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By `sort`, I meant to move the table rows having `Select` value in `Health` column to the beginning of table. Hope, I'm clear now.

Comment: so move all `Health` rows to the top?

Comment: nope. I want the complete table row to be moved up in that table. 
This is the screenshot of expected html.
https://imagebin.ca/v/3MkTfpglOG3q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? You just basically need to find anything that has the word "select" in it then append it after the header (I suggest you to use `<thead>` next time instead).

I editted your header row with the id "header"

```js
$('#decisionTable tr').each(
  function() {
  var row = $(this).find('td[id="health"]:contains("Select")');
  if (row.length)
  {
    $("#header").after($(this));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="decisionTable" class= "CSSTableGenerator" width ="100%" border =1 id="table1">
<tr color="23145" id="header">
       <th><b>CheckList</b></th>
       <th><b>Health</b></th>
       <th><b>Comments</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of Failed Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Green</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of mobile Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Select</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of Success Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Red</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of unknown Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Amber</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="checklist" data-id="checklist">
            Trend of mixed Login attempts
  </td>
  <td id="health">Select</td> 
  <td><textarea type="text" name='Comments' id="comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just let me know if you didn't understand anything, thought I didn't need too much explanation since it's pretty short